# C# DB ShortText Column Not Displaying Values

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I have a WPF/C# application I am working on that involves displaying data tables from Microsoft Access DB.  I have a Tab Control that I populate with TabItems each displaying their own data table from my database.  Each table has multiple types - all have at least one 'Short Text' Access DB type.  Only one of my tables is not displaying it's Short Text column values - I can see values for Short Text in all tables except one.

The tables are displayed/created programmatically according to the code below:

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(Constants.DB_CONN_STR);
conn.Open();
string[] restrictions = new string[4];
restrictions[3] = "Table";
DataTable tableOftables = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, restrictions);
int numTables = tableOftables.Rows.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < numTables; i++)
{
     string currTableName = tableOftables.Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString();
     // get data from table 
     OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM " + currTableName, conn);
     OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
     DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
     dataTable.Load(reader);

     // load data into data grid as read only
     DataGrid dataGridView = new DataGrid();
     dataGridView.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView;

     dataGridView.IsReadOnly = true;

     // create tab with table name, add a grid, add to tab control 
     TabItem newTableTab = new TabItem
     {
          //Header = Constants.TABLE_NAMES[i],
          Header = currTableName,
          Content = dataGridView
     };
          dbViewWindowTabControl.Items.Add(newTableTab);
}
conn.Close();
```

I have tried showing the type in a message box of multiple tables with short text:

```
if (currTableName.ToLower() == "exampletablename")
{
     MessageBox.Show(dataTable.Rows[0][dataTable.Columns["ShortTextCol"]].GetType().ToString());
}
```

With both the working and not working tables I get a pop-up showing 'System.String' - as expected.
I can also use this message to show the value of the Short Text - this works for both working and non working tables.  But for some reason one of my table's Short Text column simply does not populate any values besides the column header in my GUI.

Comment: What is the name of the column with the ShortText not displayed?

Comment: Is the column index correct? I access the column by name. Example testing for the existence of a table: `using DataTable dtTables = cnn.Native.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        return dtTables
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Any(row => ((string)row["TABLE_NAME"]).ToLowerInvariant() == tableName.ToLowerInvariant());`

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes column index where? All of the other columns have populated values

Comment: @Steve 'customer#' is the name of the column. Does it have to do with the column name containing '#'?

Comment: Isn't `currTableName = tableOftables.Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString()` a column in `tableOfTables`? And also if you use `ToLower` the string literal should be in lower case: `currTableName.ToLower() == "TableName"` like `currTableName.ToLower() == "tablename"` (but I assume that this is only an example text).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes that is just an example table name to show how I was seeing that the values were strings.  That code simply shows a message box.  The values are populated in the first code segment.  But I will change that to reflect proper syntax.  I know the column index is correct because every other column in this table and all columns in other tables show values.